# Identificar onde estou e traçar rotas (Google Maps V3 com JS)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou tentando criar um script em JS e HTML5. Preciso resolver o seguinte problema:

O usuário abre a página e aparece o mapa em um lugar pré-definido. Depois ele clica em um input e digita a localização dele, (o input fica acima do mapa), depois ele clica em um botao buscar, e no mesmo instante, uma rota é traçada do ponto onde ele está, até o lugar que já estava pré-definido anteriormente. (ex: uma empresa).

O meu código está assim:

```js
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 840});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: 'AUAU MIAU PETSHOP',
    icon: 'marker.png',
    position: new google.maps.LatLng('-18.894756', '-48.263564')
});

function initialize() {
    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: marker.position,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_content')[0], options);

    marker.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        info.setContent('Avenida Bias Fortes, 382 - Lourdes, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30170-010, Brasil');
        info.open(map, marker);
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_route').submit(function() {
        info.close();
        marker.setMap(null);

        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var request = {
            origin: $("#route_from").val(),
            destination: marker.position,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
    
});
```

```css
#map_content {
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post" id="form_route">
                                                    
  <label>Origem: 
    <input type="text" id="route_from" size="50" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Traçar rota" />
    
</form>
    
<div id="map_content"></div>
```

Como posso adapta-lo para resolver meu problema?

Comment: Para que a sua pergunta tenha uma aceitação melhor no SOpt, é importante que você mostre que você tentou resolver seu problema. O ideal é você vir aqui expor problemas específicos. Por exemplo, se você tivesse postado o seu código explicando exatamente onde ocorreu um erro, qual a mensagem de erro que você recebeu, quais são as entradas/saídas esperadas e obtidas, etc.

Comment: Obrigado, vou realizar as correções.

Comment: Esse input "Origem" (`route_from`) será preenchido com as coordenadas obtidas por geolocation, será buscado o endereço pelas coordenadas obtidas por geolocation, como é, qual será o conteúdo dele? Ele pode ser mesmo preenchido pelo usuário ou não, é automático?

Comment: Bruno, como não estava conseguindo fazer para o geolocation identificar sem o usuário ter que digitar eu coloquei ele.... mais pode tirar... foi apenas de exemplo

Comment: Geolocation html5. O usuário digita o endereço? Porque geolocalização de navegador não presta, vc vai acabar mandando o cara sair de São Paulo ou Curitiba ou algo do tipo 90% das vezes. Se for Mobile e usar o GPS desconsidere, mas se for Web mesmo coloca uma barra de endereço e usa o endereço pra traçar a rota. To sendo advogado do diabo mas é experiência, pra vc n passar raiva.

Comment: Entendi. Engraçado porque nós fóruns que visitei o pessoal tem falado muito bem do geolocation, mas concordo com seu ponto de vista. Mas se for realizar da forma que mencionou, como posso adaptar meu código?

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira geolocation funciona bem nos principais browsers, então desconsidere o IE =). Tenho alguns serviços que usa sem problemas, a precisão depende do provedor e do tipo de rede também, mas nunca tive problemas. No caso de usar o input e a pessoa informar o endereço você deve usar geocoding, o google tem serviço para isto também. Já irei incluir uma resposta com geolocation normal, coisa simples, pra você ter um note.

Comment: Beleza, fico no aguardo, pois já estou quebrando a cabeça aqui ahhha